# One icon keeps vanishing from home screen

Tags: samsung, app-icons

I have looked around for similar issue but I think mine is different.  Now and then, only 1 icon vanishes from my home screen.  It is always "Aces Cribbage" (available on Google store for free) and sometimes it won't come back after restarting. It is currently set installed on the main memory and not SD card so that is ruled out.  I have removed and reinstalled it and cleared cache.

I have a few other apps and games installed that are not having this issue (some on SD cards, some on only main memory) so I wonder if there's something with Aces Cribbage that is glitching the home screen icon?

Once in a blue moon, the icon reappears behind another icon, forcing me to rearrange a few to get that game back out and accessible again. When it is missing and I want to play it, I have to use apps screen to find the game, which is a couple steps more than having it stay on the home screen.

Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime G530, 8GB internal + 64GB SD mainly for pictures and video, less than 6 months old. Not rooted and all stock other than 64GB SD card added.